# подключение файлов без изменения путей

Tags: php, require

есть файл (условно api.php), который отвечает за API, в нём есть такая строка:

```
require_once("../file.php");
```

при ajax-запросах всё работает, но если я попытаюсь подключить api.php в другом месте через `require_once`, то получу ошибку

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../file.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in ...
```

как подключить файл без ошибок?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените на

```
require_once(__DIR__ . "/../file.php");
```